# MarkLogic Content Pump (MLCP) Error - Cannot update server-maintained properties of directory URIs

Tags: module, properties, marklogic, mlcp

I am running MLCP to copy code into a modules database and getting the following "Cannot update server-maintained properties" error(s):

> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /marklogic.rest.resource/status/assets/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /marklogic.rest.resource/addProject/assets/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /marklogic.rest.resource/integrityCheck/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /Default/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /marklogic.rest.resource/docInventory/assets/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /marklogic.rest.resource/addDoc/assets/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /marklogic.rest.resource/deleteProject/: Cannot update server-maintained properties
>
> 21/05/20 12:17:12 ERROR contentpump.DatabaseContentWriter: Error setting document properties for /Default/rts-doc-api2/rest-api/options/: Cannot update server-maintained properties

The modules actually get installed, so it looks like this is an issue with creating directory URIs.

The maintain last modified and maintain directory last modified are set to false and I am reluctant to set `-copy_properties false` and `-copy_permissions false` because I don't want to remove these for the actual modules.

The mlcp script looks like this:

```
./mlcp.sh import -host localhost -port 8000 -username ___ -password ___ -mode local -database api-modules -input_file_path /backups/api-modules -input_file_type archive -input_compressed
```

Comment: For the database that you are inserting into, what is the `directory creation` set to? `manual` or `automatic`?

Comment: Directory creation is set to automatic - I looked into that. I should have mentioned that.

Oh interesting, the problem is resolved if I set it to manual.

Comment: Set it to manual and try again

Comment: Yeah Mads, that does the trick!

Comment: So the deal is that I'm creating a Modules database and explicitly setting directory-creation to manual, but then I create a Rest Endpoint and the directory-creation reverts back to automatic. I don't know why that is happening, but I can live with MLCP errors when adding a couple of modules that have a directory URI hierarchy (e.g., /a/b/c/code.sjs) during a deployment.